# How to run selenium test case in two different nodes?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Actually I need to run my single selenium test case in two different nodes using FIREFOX browser (selenium grid) , I have started my hub using below command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role hub
```

started two Nodes with two different port nos :

Node :1

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 7575 -browser browserName=firefox,version=18,platform=WINDOWS
```

Node :2

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 8585 -browser browserName=firefox,version=18,platform=WINDOWS
```

But when i execute my test case i can view my execution only in one node other node remains still, it shows `Done :/status` but no execution has taken place

can u please help out to solve this problem

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tester approach:

- Make your test to be runnable as indipendent `.jar` file. Which means the test wil not be actually a `@Test` but some method or piece of code inside `main` method
- *Pro tip*: If you can, run the nodes against the same hub. This can be done if the computers are in same network and you can access these computers.
- If this can be done, you will just run the `.jar` file twice, telling it where the huib is, and nodes will be assigned automatically
- If this cannot be done, you will have to deploy these `.jar` files on each computer (node) and run them (requires two people in most cases)

Example:

My own computer has IP `10.131.7.11` inside local network. So I will run the **hub** and each node will just do this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://10.131.7.11:4444/grid/register -port 7575 -browser browserName=firefox,version=18,platform=WINDOWS
```

Once the nodes are running, I will run the test twice. The hub will then automatically assign browsers to concrete node.

Developer approach:

- you can use multithreading and run the test once, in two threads.

But since I am tester, I use the first approach :) And I did communicate with our developers who helped me to create multithreading test suite which is idiot proof (tested on myself :) )

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pavel Janicek . for your quick response, Above info v useful for me ...